# Why would SVG sprite XML file display as text string on server, but not locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, svg

I am trying to implement custom svg icons using an `<object>` tag, and everything works fine locally. When I push to the server, however, I get the text string of the xml file in place of my svg image.

**index.html**

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg#iconA" class="icon icon-iconA"></object>
```

**sprite.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <style><![CDATA[
      .sprite { display: none; }
      .sprite:target { display: inline; }
      ]]></style>
  </defs>

   <g class="sprite" id="iconA">
   <path fill="#000000" d="..."></path>
  </g>

  <g class="sprite" id="iconB">
    <path fill="#000000" d="..."></path>
  </g>

</svg>
```

**style.css**

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 100%;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.icon-iconA {
  width: 6.5em;
  height: 6.5em;
}
```

Furthermore, if I navigate to the absolute path of the sprite.svg file locally in the browser, I can see the contents of the file as svg images, but if I do the same on the server I get a tiny text box with a scroll bar that outputs the XML file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg ..."`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your server is sending the incorrect mime-type and the browser thinks it's plain text or XML. If so, the correct mime-type is `image/svg+xml` like in your object tag.

Comment: Yes, but the request the browser sends to retrieve the image is separate. It will look for a header like `Content-Type: image/svg+xml`. Depending on what type of server you're running this may help > http://www.ivanthevariable.com/fixing-svg-mime-type-errors/